# where to place the for-loop in existing node.js scrtip

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I have a existing script from Microsoft that generates data for an IoT hub. Script works like a charm and generates telemetry data every second. Now I want to add an Id  to the output of the code. Nothing fancy just starting at 1 and progress with every message up to 1000000

I search for the for loop and found an easy example on W3 schools. But when I use this piece of code the way I think it should be used, it does not generate code every second anymore, but continuously. and the Id field starts at 1000000 and does not add up.

The sample code from Microsoft:

```
'''var connectionString = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Using the Node.js Device SDK for IoT Hub:
//   https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node
// The sample connects to a device-specific MQTT endpoint on your IoT Hub.
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);

// Create a message and send it to the IoT hub every second
setInterval(function(){
  // Simulate telemetry.
  var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 15);
  var message = new Message(JSON.stringify({
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: 60 + (Math.random() * 20)
  }));

  // Add a custom application property to the message.
  // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 30) ? 'true' : 'false');

  console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());

  // Send the message.
  client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('message sent');
    }
  });
}, 1000);
'''
```

The way I used the for-loop:

```
'''
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

'use strict';

// The device connection string to authenticate the device with your IoT hub.
//
// NOTE:
// For simplicity, this sample sets the connection string in code.
// In a production environment, the recommended approach is to use
// an environment variable to make it available to your application
// or use an HSM or an x509 certificate.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security
//
// Using the Azure CLI:
// az iot hub device-identity show-connection-string --hub-name {YourIoTHubName} --device-id MyNodeDevice --output table
var connectionString = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Using the Node.js Device SDK for IoT Hub:
//   https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node
// The sample connects to a device-specific MQTT endpoint on your IoT Hub.
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);
**var id

for (id = 0; id < 1000000; id++) {** 

// Create a message and send it to the IoT hub every second
setInterval(function(){
  // Simulate telemetry.
  var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 15);
  var message = new Message(JSON.stringify({
    id: id, 
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: 60 + (Math.random() * 20)
  }));

  // Add a custom application property to the message.
  // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 30) ? 'true' : 'false');

  console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());

  // Send the message.
  client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('message sent');
    }
  });
}, 1000);
**};**
'''
```

How to use the for loop in the existing script so I can Add an ID to the output that starts at 1 progresses with 1 every single record up to 1000000

Comment: So, 1). you want `id + 1` to be added to every event or 2). the event should be fired for `1000000` times containing `id`?

Comment: I want Id +1 to be added for every event

Comment: What should happen after 1000000? I suspect you might want to use `setTimeout()`, otherwise you would need to use `clearInterval()` at some point. To explain `id` starting with 1000000 because **setInterval's callback** maintains (kind of final) reference to id and not the iterative value.

Comment: 100000 was just added as an endpoint because it would never reach this far. Script was used for a testcase to get some testdata for other purposes. and I needed an Id field for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the for loop, just ad id var outside the setInterval in increase it each fire:

```
// Using the Node.js Device SDK for IoT Hub:
//   https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node
// The sample connects to a device-specific MQTT endpoint on your IoT Hub.
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);
**var id

var id = 0;

// Create a message and send it to the IoT hub every second
setInterval(function(){
  id++;

  // Simulate telemetry.
  var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 15);
  var message = new Message(JSON.stringify({
    id: id, 
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: 60 + (Math.random() * 20)
  }));

  // Add a custom application property to the message.
  // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 30) ? 'true' : 'false');

  console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());

  // Send the message.
  client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('message sent');
    }
  });
}, 1000);

'''
```